# ObjectDisposedException when trying to use Dependency Injection with CreatePerOwinContext

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, unity-container

I am trying to use DI with the the OWIN `CreatePerOwinContext` extension. I am also using the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. Inside the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider I am trying to get and instance of my user manager using: OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.OwinContext.GetUserManager.

Start UP file:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
            var config = new HttpConfiguration {DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityRegistrations.GetConfiguredContainer())};
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            //Allow Cross Domain Calls
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);



            //I verified that my AppUserManager is getting constructed properly
            //var manager = UnityRegistrations.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<AppUserManager>();

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityRegistrations.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<AppUserManager>());


            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                // Point at which the Bearer token middleware will be mounted
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                // An implementation of the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider which the middleware
                // will use for determining whether a user should be authenticated or not
                Provider = new OAuthProvider("self"),
                // How long a bearer token should be valid for
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
                // Allows authentication over HTTP instead of forcing HTTPS
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); 
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

This is the `GetConfiguredContainer` method :

```
private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new 

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
         return Container.Value;
    }

    Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => {
                var container = new UnityContainer();

                //Registers the Types
                Register(container);

                return container;
            });
```

Inside the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` of my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation I try to get an instance of the `AppUserManager`:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            //Inspecting the _userManager I see the ObjectDisposedException
             _userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();


            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
        }
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible with Web API and Owin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a rookie mistake. For some reason on my `AppUserManager` Unity registration I added a `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`. This was, obviously, a mistake. It was disposing prematurely. My DbContext also has a `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` on its registration. Hours of fun!

**WRONG**

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<AppUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

**Correct**

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<AppUserManager>();
```